# Why does my fixed navigation menu become 2 lines on scroll?

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I'm really confused as to why my top navigation menu spreads out onto 2 lines sometimes. When first landing on the site, it's all on one line, but when scrolling down and then up, the last item ("Sign in") moves to the second line.

I've tried playing around with CSS but am unfortunately not good enough to pinpoint the root of the problem.

If someone can take a look that would be awesome!

Here is my URL: http://blog.koantic.com/

Thanks :)

Comment: On a macbook pro, I do not see it go into two lines on scroll. But when I shrink down the page, just before it collapses into a pancake menu, there is about 20px of space where it does go into two lines.

Comment: Hmm I think it happens more often when scrolling on individual blog posts. Any idea as to how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In style.css try adding this to line 1660:

```css
width: 100%;
display: inline-block;
```

full line would be:

```css
nav#top-menu-nav, #top-menu, nav.fullwidth-menu-nav, .fullwidth-menu {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Also change line 166 to:

```css
min-width: 520px!important
```

full line would be:

```css
ul.nav {
    min-width: 520px!important;
}
```

And change line 168 into this:

```css
.et_header_style_left .logo_container {
    width: auto;
}
```

I've discovered that if you are on the homepage, it doesn't show but on a blog-single page it will show the weird behaviour.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I have been frustrated over this all month and your css fixed the problem perfectly! :)